# Value set by ng-model is not updated in the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The following code from my view works just as expected. player_id is updated whenever I make a new selection:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="player_id" ng-change="hithere();">
        <option ng-repeat="player in players" value="{{ player.id }}">{{ player.name }}</option>
    </select>
</div>
test works: {{ player_id }}
```

Bot the code below does not work as I expect. I would expect the log to always print the same value as I see in my view. But instead it prints the default value 0, regardless of my selection in the view.

```
$scope.player_id = 0;
...
$scope.hithere = function($event){
    console.log('Test does not work, prints 0');
    console.log($scope.player_id);
};
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably a scoping issue. The `$scope` in the controller is a parent (or other ancestor) of the scope in the HTML.

Use this instead:

```
$scope.data = {
  player_id: 0
}
```

And then use `data.player_id` everywhere instead of just `player_id`.

See [Understanding Scopes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

This scenario is best candidate to use `ControllerAs` syntax.

In HTML use `ng-controller="NameOfController as vm"`

then HTML would be as follows, and you need not require to wrap your model inside extra object.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="vm.player_id" ng-change="hithere();">
        <option ng-repeat="player in vm.players" value="{{ player.id }}">{{ player.name }}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```